Present passive or present simple with participle phrase
Could you please explain grammar of the first part of the following sentence?

It is designed for the development of large applications and transpiles to JavaScript.

I guess this is present simple with participle phrase (subject + verb to be and object as a participle phrase), but for some non-explaining reasons I think of present passive simple.

non-explaining reasons? Do you mean unexplained reason? Generally, you need to try and show research or effort on your part.
